# How to implement connections between nodes in a node graph?

Tags: c++, graph, nodes

I'm trying to make a [node graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node_graph_architecture) editor in Qt and c++ (I'm kinda unfamiliar with it). There are so called nodes that act similar to functions: they take some inputs, process them and return some outputs. These inputs and outputs are represented as ports that can be connected together with edges.

Each type of node is a separate class that inherits from the `Node` base that implements some functionality for connecting the nodes together and executing them.

So I need a way to pass one node's outputs of some arbitrary type to some other node's inputs through a common interface that the base class provides. And I also need to somehow restrict which nodes can be connected together based on the type of the data that gets passed while providing an option to convert one type to another.

Here's why I'm asking this question:

In my current implementation there is an `AbstractNodeData` class that is passed by reference between nodes and gets downcasted to a specific type when the actual data needs to be accessed. Each node has a `QVector` (very similar to `std::vector`) which holds output `Port`s of the node and a `QVector` of input `Port`s. A `Port` contains some information about its parent `Node`, its capacity (how many connections it can have) and a `QVector` of `Connection` objects. A `Connection` in its turn holds a pointer to the `Node` and the index of the port it's connected to. When a node is executed it accesses its input ports and calls `getData(int connectionIndex)` on them. The method then calls the `getData()` method on the appropriate `Connection` which then calls a third `getData(int portIndex)` on a `Node` which finally returns a pointer to `AbstractNodeData`.

And this is where I started to have a lot of concerns. Here's how my thought process went: *It seems like it would be appropriate to store a pointer to a `Port` in the `Connection` object instead of a pointer to a `Node` and an index. I could also subclass `Port` to perform the type check and conversion in a virtual method.* But that would be a fourth `getData()`. Also, I already have some (unnecessary?) indirection with the `AbstractNodeData` being passed by reference and polymorphic `Port`s would mean more pointers and indirection and even dynamic allocation if I don't store the ports as members of the nodes. Then, input and output ports have very similar structure and function, except for one thing: input nodes access other nodes' data and output nodes provide that data to input ports so it makes sense to have an `InputPort` class and an `OutputPort` class that derived from `Port`. But if I'm going to subclass ports for each data type that would mean that I would have to provide two classes for each type. *Well, to eliminate the fourth `getData()` I could store a pointer to the node's output `AbstractNodeData` in `Port`.* But wouldn't this violate the encapsulation principle?

Are my concerns valid? And if so, are there any better ways of implementing connections between nodes?

Here's the code I've described (messy and unfinished):

```cpp
//Node.hpp
#pragma once

#include <QObject>
#include <QUuid>

#include "NodeData.hpp"
#include "Port.hpp"

class InputPort;
class OutputPort;

class Node : QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    virtual AbstractNodeData* getData(int outputIndex) = 0;
    virtual void execute() = 0;
protected:
    QVector<Port*> inputs;
    QVector<Port*> outputs;
private:
    QUuid uuid;
};

//Port.hpp
#pragma once

#include <QVector>

#include "Node.hpp"
#include "Connection.hpp"
#include "NodeData.hpp"

class Connection;
class Node;

class Port
{

public:
    Port(Node *node, int index, int capacity = 1);
    int getConnectionCount();
    Connection getConnection(int connectionIndex);
    virtual bool acceptsConnection();
protected:
    Node* parentNode;
    int index;
    int capacity;  
    QVector<Connection> connections;
};

class InputPort : Port
{
    AbstractNodeData* getData(int connectionIndex);
};

class OutputPort : Port
{
    AbstractNodeData* getData();
};

//Connection.hpp
#pragma once

#include <QUuid>

#include "Node.hpp"
#include "NodeData.hpp"

class Node;

class Connection
{
public:
    Connection(Node*, int);
    
    Node* getNode();
    int getPortIndex();
    
    AbstractNodeData* getData();
    
private:
    Node *node;
    int portIndex;
};


//NodeData.hpp
#pragma once

class AbstractNodeData
{
public:
    virtual int getTypeID() const = 0;
    template <typename castType>
    castType* as(){
        return dynamic_cast<castType*>(this);
    }
};

template <typename dataType>
class NodeData
{
public:
    virtual dataType get() const = 0;
    virtual void set(dataType type) const = 0;
};
```

**EDIT**:
Forgot to mention. I've looked at [this](https://github.com/paceholder/nodeeditor) repo's source code and I even borrowed some design decisions from it like the abstract node data but I think the way it's doing things is unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: Do you have an actual problem, or does your code work as expected, and you have more design questions than an actual problem? Then this probably fits better on [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @codeling The code doesn't work because it's unfinished and it's unfinished becuase I have design questions.

Comment: I think the theory of "MVVM" design pattern will help. There are some implementations of the "Node Graph" on the GitHub. Here is one of them. https://github.com/gpospelov/qt-mvvm